# Redirecionamento

Tags: wordpress

Fiz a atualização do meu site em Wordpress. Criei uma pasta chamada 2016 e, depois de atualizado meu site, movi os arquivos para a pasta principal. O problema é que quando acesso o site, ele está redirecionando para a pasta "2016", onde está fazendo as atualizações. Já acessei o banco e mudei o endereço para a pasta principal, mesmo assim continua "chamando" a pasta anterior. Como resolver essa situação?

Comment: As chamadas dentro do código estão corretas?

Comment: Sim, o apontamento da página principal, o banco de dados também. Onde mais posso verificar?

Comment: Configurou o redirecionamento no wordpress, não manjo muito, mas deve ter algo em configuração > Geral, da uma lida nas opções

Comment: Wilson, conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Acabei de resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda, David.

Comment: pode postar abaixo a resposta de como resolveu ?